# Construct Binary Tree

Tags: python-3.x

How to construct the binary tree considering the following pattern – left & right child, as well as a parent?

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = parent
```

I used the simplest pattern before.

```
tree = BinaryTree(1)
tree.left = BinaryTree(2)
tree.right = BinaryTree(3)
tree.left.left = BinaryTree(4)
tree.left.left.left = BinaryTree(6)
tree.left.right = BinaryTree(5)

#              1
#            /   \
#           2     3
#         /  \
#        4    5
#       /
#      6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parents of the child widgets as well. Since the parents are known at the moment that the children are initialised you could use the `parent` parameter of `BinaryTree.__init__`, i.e.

```
tree.left = BinaryTree(2, parent=tree)
tree.left.left = BinaryTree(4, parent=tree.left)
```

etc.

Comment: Any option to use child reference `left=...` & `right=...` in class right from the beginning?